# change tableview row height in ios 5

Tags: uitableview, ios5

Before ios 5 I would set the row height in a tableview like this:

```
self.tableView.rowHeight=71;
```

However, it doesn't work on iOS5.

Someone has an idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Have you tried `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` from `UITableViewDelegate`?

You may set the row height to 71 by implementing `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` in your `UITableView` delegate (one who supports the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol).

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 71.0;
}
```

First you should set a delegate of your tableView. Delegate should conform to the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol. Let's say we have a `TableDelegate` class. To conform to a `UITableViewDelegate` protocol one should have it in square brackets in it's declaration like this:

```
...    
@interface TableDelegate : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate>
...
or
@interface TableDelegate : UIViewController <some_other_protocol, UITableViewDelegate>
```

Then you set the delegate:

```
...
// create one first
TableDelegate* tableDelegate = [[TableDelegate alloc] init];
...
self.tableView.delegate = tableDelegate;
```

In the end you should implement the `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method in the `TableDelegate` implementation:

```
@implementation TableDelegate
...
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 71.0;
}
...
@end
```

## rowHeight

Just to clarify, using `rowHeight` should work just fine and perform better than constant returned from `-tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` as Javier Soto points out in the comments. Also note, that if your UITableView has delegate returning height in `-tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` and `rowHeight` property set, prior value is honoured.

Comment: Check Apple warning on using this implementation instead of setting rowHeight: There are performance implications to using tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: instead of the rowHeight property. Every time a table view is displayed, it calls tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: on the delegate for each of its rows, which can result in a significant performance problem with table views having a large number of rows (approximately 1000 or more).

Answer (score 3):

Im coding for iOS 5 and it actually works. You just need to implement the line you said in the:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
```

method after the:

```
[super viewDidLoad];
```

The:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method does not work if the TableView is empty. But if you use the rowHeight property it will work even if the view is empty.

Answer (score 1):

This method is change the Height of row

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    return  51.0f
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `rowHeight` *before* `viewWillAppear:`, e.g. right after creating your table view.

This made it work for me on iOS 5. On iOS 6 it's easier: you can set it anywhere.

The advantage of using `rowHeight`, as pointed out by others, is that you avoid the performance impact of `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`.